# Markup a difficult navigation table

Tags: html, css

Help is needed. I could not think of a solution. How to fix the problem with the layout or perhaps there is an option to better create a similar table:

[source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DitCL.png)

current solution:

```css
.navTable {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.navTest {
    display: block;
}

.navTableTest {
    float: right;
}

.navTableBody {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: table-row-group;
}

.navTableCell {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.navTableRow {
    display: table-row;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.navTableRow:nth-child(1) .new{
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

.navTableRow div:nth-child(1) .new{
    border-left: 1px solid;
}

.navTableRow:nth-child(1) .new:hover{
    border-top: 1px solid #f60;
}

.navTableRow div:nth-child(1) .new:hover{
    border-left: 1px solid #f60;
}

.new {
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: solid 0.5px #666;
    border-right: solid 0.5px #666;
}

.new:hover {
    color: #666;
    border: solid 0.5px #f60;
}

.new:visited {
    color: #666;
}

.new.last {
    border-top: solid 0.5px #666;
}

.new.info {
    border: solid 0.5px #666;
}

.new.info:hover {
    color: #666;
    border: solid 0.5px #f60;
}

.newText {
    color: #666;
}

.navTableRow:nth-child(1) .current{
    border-top: 1px solid #f60;
}

.navTableRow div:nth-child(1) .current{
    border-left: 1px solid #f60;
}

.navTableRow:nth-child(1) .current:hover{
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
}

.navTableRow div:nth-child(1) .current:hover{
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
}

.current {
    color: #f60;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: solid 0.5px #f60;
    border-right: solid 0.5px #f60;
}

.current:hover {
    border: solid 0.5px #666;
}

.current:visited {
    color: #f60;
}

.current.info {
    border: solid 0.5px #f60;
}

.current.info:hover {
    border: solid 0.5px #666;
}

.currentText {
    color: #f60;
}

.current.last {
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

.navTableRow:nth-child(1) .done{
    border-top: 1px solid #f60;
}

.navTableRow div:nth-child(1) .done{
    border-left: 1px solid #f60;
}

.navTableRow:nth-child(1) .done:hover{
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
}

.navTableRow div:nth-child(1) .done:hover{
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
}

.done {
    background-color: #f60;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: solid 0.5px #f60;
    border-right: solid 0.5px #f60;
}

.done:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 0.5px solid #666;
}

.done:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

.done.info {
    border: solid 0.5px #f60;
}

.done.info:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: solid 0.5px #666;
}

.doneText {
    color: #f60;
}

.done.last {
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

.testNavInfo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.testNavInfo p {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
}

.testNavInfo h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navInfoCell {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.navInfoCell span {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navTable testNavTable ">
                                    <div class="navTableBody">
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="done" href="#">1.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="done" href="#">1.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="done" href="#">1.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="current" href="#">1.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">1.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">1.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">1.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">1.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">1.9</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">1.10</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">1.11</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.9</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.10</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">2.11</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new last" href="#">2.12</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new last" href="#">2.13</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.9</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.10</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.11</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.12</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.13</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.14</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.15</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">3.16</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.9</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.10</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.11</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.12</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">4.13</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.9</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.10</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">5.11</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">6.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">6.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">6.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">6.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">6.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">6.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">6.7</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">7.8</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.9</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">8.10</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">9.9</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navTableRow">
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.1</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.2</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.3</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.4</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.5</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.6</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.7</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.8</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.9</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.10</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.11</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.12</a></div>
                                            <div class="navTableCell"><a class="new" href="#">10.13</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

but there is a problem 2.12, 2.13 line curve because of the fact that the row above does not have a border

[result problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44v64.png)